# Is there a word for measuring "how easily change can happen or be made"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

If one word exists, I will call it X.

X would describe how easily change can happen or be made, in general. Example:

> This building is made out of legos, so it has a high X, thus making it easy to make changes to it.

> The wind today can be very weak or very strong. Either way, it's gonna have high X.

> Making a sculpture out of stone is hard. You can only take bits out of it and doing that is not very easy neither precise. The stone has low X.

I'd imagine X would be used in physics for example.

Comment: I was going to suggest _mutability_ but that doesn't really work well for the second example.

Comment: Mutability is actually something I was looking for. I'm pleased with that if no better word will come up. Maybe that high level word does not really exists which works for all the examples I provided.

Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Check out [synonyms for ***malleable***](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/malleable) And I don't know if they'd be "acceptable" to your target audience / readership, but I'm sure ***workableness, workability*** would be easily ***understood*** in context.

Comment: The second example is of a different class from the first and third. The reason is that the strength of the wind is not under anyone's control while constructions and sculptures are the products of human activity. The most familiar adjective to me for variabiliy in weather conditions is "changeable". Winds can be _changeable_ as can cloud patterns and precipitation. The nature of the wind could be referred to as its 'changeability' and your second sentence could be written as _"The wind today can be very weak or very strong. Either way, it's gonna have high **changeability**."_

Comment: Yes you are right, @BoldBen, they fit into different classes. Changeability seems about right too. Thanks!

Comment: 'Labile' is used for 'readily open to change', but the noun 'lability' is rarely used other than in the sense of proneness of people to make errors, have lapses.

Comment: I agree with @BoldBen that there's no single word covering the two different concepts, other than the obvious unifying theme of *changeability* - a word one can easily find by looking up "change" in a thesaurus, i.e. doing some basic research. I'm therefore voting to close this question. `@hello`, this isn't meant as criticism: EL&U is a bit different from other Q&A sites, and it takes a while to get the hang of our site's somewhat stricter expectations. As a start, I recommend reading [ask] and taking our site **[Tour]**. :-)